# How to change Action Bar/Title Bar font?

Tags: android, fonts, android-actionbar

Not sure if this is called the action bar or the title bar but I need to change the font to a font I have in my assets folder. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: can post your xml code??

Answer (score 4):

As some other users have suggested, you can use a toolbar, but if you don't want to or you have to keep using the action bar, then you can define the style of the action bar in your style like this:

```
<style name="baseStyle" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/myActionBarStyle</item>
  ...
</style>
```

and inside `myActionBarStyle` define the font:

```
  <style name="myActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/customFont</item>
    ...
  </style>
```

this will affect the font only in the action bar and not in the whole app

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom toolbar. below is code snapshot

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and then you can access toolbar_title in your java class(Activity or Fragment) and set a custom font style.

Answer (score 0):

You can access textview of your toolbar like this:

```
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

And then assign needed font:

```
mTitle.setTypeface(someTypeface);
```

Comment: How do I access the toolbar variable? Doesn't exist in my activity when I start typing it.

Comment: Do you use toolbar or action bar

Comment: Not sure. It is the default when you create an empty activity. I'm not referencing it in my xml or java though.

Comment: Or try Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

Answer (score 0):

In java code

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#2B1C27")));

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titleview_2, null);

TextView actionbar_title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
actionbar_title.setTypeface(you can set your font here also.);

actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

in XML file

```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:id="@+id/actionBar"
     android:paddingTop="7dp"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="#9B66AB">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/appTitle"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

It will work.

**EDITED**

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle((Html.fromHtml("<font face=\"Times New Roman\">" + getString(R.string.title) + "</font>")));
```

Comment: This adds another bar under the existing bar. I'm trying to edit the existing bar which comes as default when you create the project.

Comment: When I apply the code you gave me titleview_2 shows up as red (Cannot resolve symbol 'titleview_2')

Comment: Give your layout name as titleview_2.

Answer (score 0):

First Go to styles.xml and the add

Font Name

In Your Theme Tag...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically in java then you can paste the below code in OnCreate method in your activity. It works for the later api versions.

```
        Typeface typeface = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.lilitaoneregular);
        }
        SpannableString str = new SpannableString("Daily Khabar");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            str.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(typeface),0, str.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        actionBar.setTitle(str);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try the following :-

ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle("New Title");

Comment: The Question is about Custom fonts but you wrote about app bat title.

Answer (score -2):

"Android O introduces a new feature, Fonts in XML". You now can make a custom toolbar and use the

```
android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"
```

XML tag. You need to add your font to the recources/font folder. For more info see https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html